# looping over multidimensional array outputs individual characters

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

After an `ajax` call, my `php` script `echo`s out a `json_encode`d multidimensional array. When I loop over the array in my javascript, it iterates over each individual character instead of the top-level array elements. Why?

js

```
    $('.test').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://domain.com/my/script,
        }).done(function(multidimensionalArray) {
            console.log(multidimensionalArray);         //outputs the seemingly correct array
            console.log(multidimensionalArray.length);  //outputs number of characters (instead of the expected 20...)
        })
    });
```

php

```
public function calledByAjax() {
    $items = namespace\items\GetList::getAll(array(
        'limit' => 20 // This appropriately limits the results to 20, which is why 20 is expected above in the js
    ));

    $items_array = array();
    foreach($items as $key=>$item){
        $temp = array (
            'attr1' => $item->getPrivateVar1(),
            'attr2' => $item->getPrivateVar2(),
            'attr3' => $item->getPrivateVar3(),
        );
        $items_array[$key] = $temp;
    }
    echo json_encode($items_array);
    exit(0);
}
```

console.log(multidimensionalArray)

```
[{"attr1":"The variable","attr2":"the variable","attr3":"the variable"},...
...so on for 20 items...
]
```

console.log(multidimensionalArray.length)

```
1562
```

Comment: You might want to post the JSON received by the client.

Comment: Also, what happens if you change to `exit (json_encode($items_array));`?

Comment: And also, add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before echo'ing anything.

Comment: @user1032531 What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not working with an object but with a string.

You need to make sure that the returned output from your php script (a string) gets parsed as json. The easiest way to do that is to specify the `dataType`:

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://domain.com/my/script',
        dataType: 'json'   // the expected data type is json, 
                           // jQuery will parse it automatically
    }).done(function(multidimensionalArray) {
        console.log(multidimensionalArray);         //outputs the seemingly correct array
        console.log(multidimensionalArray.length);  //outputs number of characters (instead of the expected 20...)
    })
});
```